# How do I solve $x = y - (y * 0.27)$ for $y$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been struggling to get '$y$' out of this equation for the last few hours but using all the rules of transposition I know and searching Google has not helped.

Can anyone solve $$x = y - (y \cdot z)$$ for $y$ please?

For example,

$$32.85 = y - (y \cdot 0.27)$$

So in this case $y = 45$.

I'm trying to reverse engine a percentage decrease, to get the original number for $y$.

Comment: The first step is to realise that
$$
y - y \times z = (1-z) \times y
$$
Then divide both sides by $1-z$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Write $$x=y(1-z)$$ to solve this problem

Comment: Thank you, so the answer is x / (1 - z) = y.

Comment: Yes, this is right, if $$z\ne 1$$

Comment: Would you mind explaining to me the rule about this, as it looks like you swap the minus outside the brackets for the times inside and y becomes a 1. Sorry, I'm a programmer not a mathematician, thanks

Comment: Write $$x=y\cdot 1-yz$$ and then you will get $$x=y(1-z)$$

Comment: Excellent, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$1£-0.27£=0.73£$

What about $1y-0.27y$?